# PHP mail set from image

Tags: php, sendmail, postfix-mta

When I send an email to somebody, there is this avatar of me (in this case from my Google+ account)

How can I extend my PHP `mail()` function to add an avatar in the emails?

Comment: Eeh.. what have you got so far?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `mail()`. Just add an `<img>` tag to the html-body of the email

Comment: The answer that is given is exactly what I was searching for. I was looking into opengraph etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These avatars are a feature provided by the used mail client, e.g.:

- GMail will show the user's Google+ profile avatar if available
- Apple Mail will show the user's avatar shown in your address book
- etc.

So the avatar is not part of the mail itself.

Two workaround suggestions:

- Use a GMail sender address assigned to your Google+ profile.
- Add a VCard as attachement, see [Formatting VCard in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190249/formatting-vcard-in-php) and http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html#publish - so the recipient gets a VCard to import into his address book.