# Create .vcf file. [PHP]

Tags: javascript, php

I access contacts from my mobile using `Cordova` then making that contact in string form like this.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:John Doe
N:John Doe ;;;;
TEL;TYPE=mobile:34458777452
NOTE:
NICKNAME:
END:VCARD
```

after making string i send data in PHP to save vCard. in '*.vcf' form.
But when i am open that file using `Nokia PC Suite` it show me like this figure below
[image]

Here is my sample code
First javascript part

```
$(function(){
        var vcfData = 'BEGIN:VCARD';
        vcfData += '\n';
        vcfData += 'VERSION:3.0';
        vcfData += '\n';
        vcfData += 'FN:John Doe';
        vcfData += '\n';
        vcfData += 'N:John Doe ;;;;';
        vcfData += '\n';
        vcfData += 'TEL;TYPE=mobile:34458777452';
        vcfData += '\n';
        vcfData += 'NOTE:';
        vcfData += '\n';
        vcfData += 'NICKNAME:';
        vcfData += '\n';
        vcfData += 'END:VCARD';
        console.log(vcfData);
        var params = {
            data:vcfData
        }
        var sUrl = 'test.php';
        $.ajax({
            url:sUrl,
            method:'POST',
            data:params,
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

and in php i made a file like this.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$myfile = fopen('demo.vcf', "w");
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

**Note**
I dont want to use any php classes for making vcf file (if possible)

Comment: according to the 2nd [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190249/formatting-vcard-in-php) u need to end the vcf with `\n`

Comment: i add this `vcfData += '\n';` at the end but same error.

Comment: Try replacing all \n with \r\n then, as shown in that answer as well